How to render a separate line of code from livewire blade view into an other blade file?
Hello I am working with livewire laravel and I want to render a separate lines of code from the livewire blade file into another blade file if that even possible.
I have a file called expedition.blade.php it has to parts I want to render on differnt positions on the bladeview
Here is the code for expedition.blade.php
{{-- THIS IS PART 1 STARTS   --}}
    <div class="p-3 bg-white2 transition-shadow rounded hover:shadow-lg dark:border-jacarta-700 dark:bg-jacarta-700 text-jacarta-700 dark:text-white">
        <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
            <input id="default-radio-1" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="490" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
            <label for="default-radio-1" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
                à domicile: 500 DA</label>
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
            <input id="default-radio-2" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="315" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
            <label for="default-radio-2" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
                StopDesk: 315 DA</label>
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center">
            <input id="default-radio-3" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="0" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
            <label for="default-radio-3" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Retrait
                en magasin</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{-- THIS IS PART 1 ENDS   --}}

**THIS IS THE FIRST PART OF CODE **
{{-- THIS IS PART 2 STARTS   --}}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="item-name" class="mb-2 block font-display text-jacarta-700 dark:text-white">Wilaya<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
            <span></span>
            <select name="wilaya_id" id="wilaya" wire:model.live="wilayaID" class="w-full dropdown-toggle  items-center justify-between rounded-lg border border-jacarta-100
             bg-white py-3 px-3 dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-jacarta-300">
                <option value="" selected>---Choisir---</option>
                @foreach ($wilayas as $wilaya)
                <option value="{{ $wilaya->id }}">{{ $wilaya->nom }}</option>
                @endforeach
                <input type="submit" name="wilaya" value="{{ $wilaya->nom }}" hidden>

            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="item-name" class="mb-2 block font-display text-jacarta-700 dark:text-white">Commune<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
            <select name="commune_id" id="commune" wire:model.live="communeID" class="w-full dropdown-toggle  items-center justify-between rounded-lg border border-jacarta-100
            bg-white py-3 px-3 dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-jacarta-300">
                <option value="">Choisissez la commune</option>
                @foreach ($communes as $commune)
                <option value="{{ $commune->id }}">{{ $commune->nom }}</option>

                @endforeach

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{-- THIS IS PART 2 ENDS --}}

AND THIS IS THE 2ND PART OF CODE
P.S They are in the same blade file expedition.blade.php
What Iam trying to do is To is to render them on the same differnt file but each part separately.
FOR EXAMPLE
<div class="mb-6">
                                    {{-- <input name="wilaya" value="{{ $wilaya }}" type="text" id="item-name"
                                    class="w-full rounded-lg border-jacarta-100 py-3 hover:ring-2 hover:ring-accent/10
                                    focus:ring-accent dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-white dark:placeholder:text-jacarta-300"
                                    placeholder="Nom de votre ville" required="" disabled> --}}
                                    @livewire('**FIRST PART OF THE CODE** ')
                                    
                                </div>

And
<div class="flex justify-between mb-2">
                                <span style="padding-top:45px">Expédition</span>
                                @livewire('**Second part of the code**')
                            </div>

I haven't tried anything because am new to livewire So Please tell me if it is possible .?
Thanks.
